# IllegalStateExpection : FirebaseApp name [DEFAULT] already exists?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, kotlin, firebase-authentication

Basically, I am trying to redirect my users to separate activities based on their user roles, which my system is trying to judge through the credentials they enter.

But suddenly my app is crashing is giving out this following error:-

> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                     Process: com.devanshisukhija.sicsrattendance, PID: 13964
>                     java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create application com.devanshisukhija.sicsrattendance.Controller.App: java.lang.IllegalStateException: FirebaseApp name [DEFAULT] already exists!
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5743)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap1(Unknown Source:0)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1656)
>                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
>                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)

<> I am not sure where I am going wrong? Here, have a look at my Login activity:

```js
package com.devanshisukhija.sicsrattendance.Controller

import android.os.Bundle
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.util.Log
import android.view.View
import android.widget.Toast
import com.devanshisukhija.sicsrattendance.R
import com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_login.*


/**
 *  Comments template :-
 *  - //[START ]
 *  - //[End ]
 *
 */

class LoginActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    val TAG = "LoginActivity"
    //private var mDatabaseReference: DatabaseReference? = null
    //private var mDatabase: FirebaseDatabase? = null

    // Firebase refferences for Authentication.
    private var mAuth: FirebaseAuth? = null
    private var mUser : FirebaseUser? = null
    private var mDatabase : FirebaseDatabase? = null
    private var mDatabaseReference : DatabaseReference? = null
    private var mAuthListener : FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener? = null

    //global variables
    private var emailString : String? = null
    private var passwordString : String? = null

    lateinit var mValueEventListener : ValueEventListener
    lateinit var mDataSnapshot: DataSnapshot

    // ActivityState : ONCREATE.
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login)

        if (!FirebaseApp.getApps(this).isEmpty()) {
            FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().setPersistenceEnabled(true)
        }

        // initializing firebase Auth and database Reference.
        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()
        mDatabase = DatabaseHelper.getInstance()
        mDatabaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference
        // getting the currently logined user.
        mUser = mAuth?.currentUser


    }
    //ActivityState : ONSTART.
    override fun onStart() {
        super.onStart()

        //[START auth_state_listener]
        mAuth?.addAuthStateListener(mAuthListener!!)
    }
    //ActivityState : ONPAUSE.
    override fun onPause() {
        super.onPause()


    }

    // function for when the login button is clicked.
    // TODO : Login Activity : Function# 1.
     fun loginBtnClicked(view : View) {

         emailString = loginEmailTxt.text.toString()
         passwordString = loginPasswordtxt.text.toString()

         if(!emailString.isNullOrEmpty() && !passwordString.isNullOrEmpty()) {

             // Checking if the login cridentials are correct. and then changing the Auth State to logged in.
             //TODO : Login Activity : Function# 3.
             mAuth!!.signInWithEmailAndPassword(emailString!!, passwordString!!).addOnCompleteListener(this) { task ->

                 if(task.isSuccessful) {
                        val uid = mUser!!.uid
                     // function call for checking the user.
                        var ref = mDatabaseReference?.child("Users")?.child("Faculty")

                    // { Here below, trying retrive a key by its value.
                     ref?.addValueEventListener(mValueEventListener)
                     mValueEventListener.onDataChange(mDataSnapshot)
                     mDataSnapshot.children.forEach {
                         if (it.value == uid) {
                             Log.d("", it.key)
                         }
                         else {
                             Log.d("WOWOWO", " nononononono")
                         }
                     }

                 } else {

                     Log.e(TAG, "signInWithEmail:failure", task.exception)
                     Toast.makeText(this@LoginActivity, "Authentication failed. Make sure email and password are correct",
                             Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                 }
             } // <-----------------End of SignInwithEmailandPassword func.-------------------------->

         } else {
             Toast.makeText(this, "Email or Password can not be empty.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
         } // <----------------End of isOrnot email and password Empty condition.------------------------->
    } //<----------------------End of Login Button clicked.------------>


    // TODO : Login Activity : Function#2
     fun getHelpImgClicked(view : View) {
        val builder = AlertDialog.Builder(this)
        val dialogView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.get_help_dialog, null)
        builder.setView(dialogView)
                .setNegativeButton("Close" ){ _, _ -> }.show()

        }

    //TODO : Login Activity : Function#3
    fun checkUsertype() {


    }




}
```

Also, my application class:

```html
package com.devanshisukhija.sicsrattendance.Controller

import android.app.Application
import com.devanshisukhija.sicsrattendance.BuildConfig
import com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp
import com.google.firebase.FirebaseOptions

class App : Application() {

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()

        val options = FirebaseOptions.Builder()
                .setApplicationId(BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID)
                .setApiKey("AIzaSyBUFy5QFOK1YDqJu4uatksBGX9nR2B4obM")
                .setDatabaseUrl("https://sicsr-d4771.firebaseio.com")
                .build()
            FirebaseApp.initializeApp(this, options)
    }
}
```

Comment: You double posted the `LoginActivity` code, can you post your `App`?

Comment: edited it, please check.

Comment: Why are you calling initializeApp?  That should happen automatically if you did a normal integration with Firebase.  The error message is actually trying to tell you this.